# The first datagrid in project always bugs out, how to fix this?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013

**Edit:** So reinstalling my whole system solved the issue.
Now i am not exactly sure if this is good or bad, but at least i can go on coding now. Id REALLY love to find someone that could explain what has happened here tho and how to avoid this / fix it without setting up the system again.

I can only guess that blend murdered some DLLs that did not get reinstalled by simply reinstalling Visual Studio, but that is a guess at best.

**Start of original Question:**

Ever since i changed the color of a datagrid in Blend, my whole project seems to be flawed concerning the first datagrid. Always. How can i track down this nasty beast and fix it? Below is the whole sample code + all the things i tried, including the strange results.

I am getting this error:

"System.InvalidOperationException" in "PresentationFramework.dll"

edit: also getting THIS in every project now, about 6 of the same, with differend dll's...

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll" loaded. PDB-Datei could not be found or opened.

from the innerText (semi translated, sorry): a row of collections got some unusual changed event handlers. Index shows as 1 but should be 10"

I am having 3 datagrids in my project, here is the full xaml code for them:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagridRouten1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid x:Name="datagridRouten2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid x:Name="datagridRouten3" VerticalAlignment="Top">
</DataGrid>
```

Also there are 3 identical list in my project, like these:

```
 List<Route> listRoute1 = new List<Route>();                
 List<Route> listRoute2 = new List<Route>();               
 List<Route> listRoute2 = new List<Route>();
```

The corresponding class is:

```
public class Route
{
    public string strStartHafen { get; set; }
    public string strZielHafen { get; set; }
    public string strWarenLoadedStart { get; set; }
    public string strWarenLoadedZiel { get; set; }
}
```

Now i am really unsure why a color change does this, but it gets worse.

- I tried deleting said datagrid. Now datagrid2 shows the error.
- Then i tried to change the databinding to another list, same
  problem.
- Switching the "not working" list to another datagrid works fine, so i guess a badly formated list is out.
- I deleted every datagrid, put a new one with a differend name in my project: Same
  bug.
- Then added a second datagrid: this one is working with every of
  my 3 lists.
- Deleted the first one again, now the remaining shows the
  error.

Comment: Post the XAML of the "color change" you performed.

Comment: There is no color change anymore. And i never looked at the xaml for that one to be honest. As i said: i did this in Blend. So i clicked the datagrid and set the color to something greyish. Started the project and got said error. Reverted the color change and the error persisted. The above XAML is the full xaml, nothing left out. Actually i tried deleting the whole project but these few lines and the error persists still.

Comment: It sounds to me like Blend has done something to your project crashing. I have heard of people having issues bouncing between blend and visual studio.

Comment: Actually i fear Blend did worse... i just created a new project and that is showing the same Error. I was able to find a few lines of funny lucking stuff there tho, added the OP. Maybe someone knows how i can resolve this. Smells like having to reinstall the whole VS suit for some reason :-/

Comment: Reinstalling VS did not solve the issue. Also new projects show the same error. I really fear to have to reinstall my whole system... and with my luck the issue is still there then because i missed something. This is really not fun at all. Will stay clear of Blend in the future.